# How to resize elements dynamically inside a div based on some particular conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main div(size can be resizeable on drag), which has some sub-elements in it.

The number of subelements are dynamic(count will come from API).

So there are some conditions like if the value of subelement is between 0 to 50 there should be one size, and if it is between 51 to 200 it should of different size but greater than the previous range of 0 to 50, similarly some conditions. Basically, the size should be dependent on the value of the subelement.

On resize am able to get the main div height, but struggling to get the correct calculation to fit all the subelements in the main div with dynamic sizes.

I am trying to achieve something like this,
[image]
in the image, each subelement has different sizes based upon the value, here in my case that div is also resizable by dragging.

the code for main div,

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="st`enter code here`_content">
        <div class="row height_full">
          <div class="stock_value"> 

            .....

          </div>

          <div class="stock_value"> 

            ....

          </div>

          <div class="stock_value"> 

            ....

          </div>

          ...
          ...
          ...

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the part

```
    <div class="stock_value"> 

        ....

      </div>
```

will be in a for loop,

```
 for(var i=0; i<sub_ele.length; i++){
      <div class="stock_value" style="width:`+w_d+`px; height:`+h_d+`px;"> 

        ....

      </div>
 }
```

Am currently trying to give size in % wise, like some % of the main div,

```
     heightsd = $(".maindiv").height();
     widthsd = $(".maindiv").width();

      if(data[data.length-1]['high'] < 0){

        w_d = widthsd * 0.2;
        h_d = heightsd * 0.2;
      }else if(data[data.length-1]['high'] > 0 && data[data.length-1]['high'] < 50){

        w_d = widthsd * 0.30;
        h_d = heightsd * 0.30;
        }else if(){ .... }
        .....
```

But it is not working as expected, it is creating empty gaps in the div.

Am not getting any idea how to fit all the subelements in div with specific sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create divs with specific sizes inside a re-sizable parent div. Children that have a value of 0 to 50 have a fixed size, as well as children that have a value of 51 to 200 and so on. You are having a problem with creating unwanted gaps in the grid upon resizing, due to the fixed sizes of the tiles. Is that right?

Have a look at the [Masonry API](https://masonry.desandro.com/), I think it might have what you're looking for as it automatically fits the children elements in the appropriate place.

Comment: am also changing the children size when parent div size changes, if you see its not fixed size, its some percentage of the main div(re-sizable parent div)

Comment: I misunderstood when you said "should be one size". You can still use Masonry for this, though, even with the elements not having a fixed size. Another good one is Packery. https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/349

Comment: I have integrated Masonary, still, I can see some gaps between blocks